# Bluetooth Rechargeable Mouse that uses AA batteries

Tags: bluetooth, mice

Rechargeable batteries have existed for quite some time, and Bluetooth peripherals have had time to mature as well. Does a Bluetooth mouse exist that draws its power from a AA battery, but can also recharge that battery inside of it, via a Micro USB port or similar?

If not, which engineering challenges prevent such a product? If these products do exist, but cost an exorbitant amount, why?

Answer (score 2):

While I did not do much research on this because you did not have any real requirements other than replaceable batter and bluetooth.  I have found this mouse on [Amazon Mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001126PDM).

Based on the reviews the batteries are replaceable and the mouse is rechargeable.  I am not sure if it requires AA or AAA but should work for your purposes.

Comment: That one uses AAA, but impressive find nonetheless.